# Angular Function not getting called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Script:

```
    var AAMVC = angular.module('AAMVC', []);
var SportsController = function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/SportApi/Get")
    .success(function (response) {
        obj = JSON.parse(response);
        $scope.sports = angular.fromJson(obj);

    });


        getCountries = function (id) {
        $http.get("/api/SportApi/GetCountry/")
      .success(function (response) {
          obj = JSON.parse(response);
          $scope.countries = angular.fromJson(obj);

      });

    }
```

Now i want to call my function getCountries from my CSHTML page in MVC, but nothing happens.

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="SportsController">
    <div style="float:left">


        <h3>SPORTS</h3>

        <table class="CSSTableGenerator">
            <tr ng-repeat="s in sports">
                <td>

                    <button ng-click="getCountries(s.id)">{{s.name}}</button>

            </tr>

           <tr ng-repeat="c in countries">
                <td>
                    {{c.name}}
                </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and nothing happens, the functions doesn't ever get called, what to do? is there a easy fix?

Comment: you are not creating your getCountries function on your $scope

Comment: $scope.getCountries is what @PatrickEvans is talking about

Comment: Oh nice, it is working, but the ID is not passed @PatrickEvans

Comment: @PatrickEvans I added + id on the function where it was needed, but now nothing again..

Comment: update the code above to reflect what you currently have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `getCountries` declaration to this:

```
$scope.getCountries = function ...
```